# Como mantener el color de fondo de una fila al realizar un ordenamiento? Apps Script de google

Tags: google-apps-script

Necesito su ayuda tengo este codigo que lo que hace bien es el ordenamiento por medio de la columna direccion ip, el problema surge cuando hago lo siguiente ejemplo:

Fila 2 - Direcion IP: 10.20.20.8 con color de fondo azul
Fila 3 - Direcion IP: 10.20.20.9 con color de fondo azul
Fila 4 - Direcion IP: 10.20.20.10 con color de fondo azul
Fila 5 - Direcion IP: 10.20.20.11 con color de fondo azul
y si intento ingresar una nueva fila
Fila 6 - Direcion IP: 10.20.20.7 con color de fondo rojo
el resultado que me de da es el siguiente
Fila 2 - Direcion IP: 10.20.20.7 con color de fondo azul
Fila 3 - Direcion IP: 10.20.20.8 con color de fondo azul
Fila 4 - Direcion IP: 10.20.20.9 con color de fondo azul
Fila 5 - Direcion IP: 10.20.20.10 con color de fondo azul
Fila 6 - Direcion IP: 10.20.20.11 con color de fondo rojo
cuando deberia de ser asi 
Fila 2 - Direcion IP: 10.20.20.7 con color de fondo rojo
Fila 3 - Direcion IP: 10.20.20.8 con color de fondo azul
Fila 4 - Direcion IP: 10.20.20.9 con color de fondo azul
Fila 5 - Direcion IP: 10.20.20.10 con color de fondo azul
Fila 6 - Direcion IP: 10.20.20.11 con color de fondo azul
cabe mencionar que no tengo solo la columna Direccion IP, si no que tengo mas columnas, pero solo puse esa porque es la que utilizo para el ordenamiento

```
function onOpen() {
  ordenarIPs();
}

function onEdit() {  
  var hojaActiva = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var filasAntes = hojaActiva.getMaxRows();  
  
  var filasDespues = hojaActiva.getMaxRows();
  
  // Verificar si se eliminó una fila
  if (filasDespues < filasAntes) {
    ordenarIPs();
  }
}

function ordenarIPs() {
  // Obtiene la hoja activa
  var hojaActiva = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();

  // Obtiene el rango de datos de la hoja
  var rangoDatos = hojaActiva.getDataRange();

  // Obtiene los valores de la primera fila (cabecera)
  var cabecera = rangoDatos.offset(0, 0, 1).getValues()[0];

  // Obtiene el índice del campo "DIRECCION IP"
  var campoOrdenar = cabecera.indexOf("DIRECCION IP") + 1;

  // Obtiene el número de filas en la hoja (excluyendo la cabecera)
  var lastRow = hojaActiva.getLastRow() - 1;

  // Verifica si existen datos y se encontró el campo a ordenar
  if (lastRow > 0 && campoOrdenar > 0) {
    // Obtiene los valores de los datos (excluyendo la cabecera)
    var datos = rangoDatos.offset(1, 0, lastRow).getValues();
    Logger.log(datos);
    var coloresFondo = rangoDatos.offset(1, 0, lastRow).getBackgrounds();
    Logger.log(coloresFondo);

    // Ordena los datos en base al campo "DIRECCION IP"
    datos.sort(function (a, b) {
      return ipNumero(a[campoOrdenar - 1]) - ipNumero(b[campoOrdenar - 1]);
    });    
    // Vuelve a insertar los datos ordenados en las filas correspondientes
    for (var i = 0; i < datos.length; i++) {
      hojaActiva.getRange(i + 2, 1, 1, datos[i].length).setValues([datos[i]]);
      hojaActiva.getRange(i + 2, 1, 1, datos[i].length).setBackgrounds([coloresFondo[i]]);
    }
    Logger.log(coloresFondo);
  }
}

function ipNumero(ip){
  // Convierte una dirección IP en un número
  var ipArray = ip.split(".");
  var ipNumero = 0;

  for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    ipNumero += parseInt(ipArray[i] * Math.pow(256, 3 - i));
  }

  return ipNumero;
}
```

Comment: Hola, prueba explicando cuál es el objetivo que quieres lograr, por ejemplo, explicar cuando las filas deben ser de un color u otro, si a medida que se vayan agregando las filas deben mantener el orden, etc.

Comment: Hola @CarlosVidalVidal, el ordenamiento me funciona bien cuando agrego y elimino una fila el orden se mantiene, lo unico que no logro hacer es que cuando haga el ordenamiento tambien se lleven el color de fondo todas las filas que se muevan

Answer (score 1):

Lo que entiendo es que quieres que al ordenar los registros de la tabla, cada datos se lleve su respectivo formato de fondo a la fila donde sea movido. Para lograr esto, se me ocurre que en el array donde guardas los datos de toda la tabla, agregues una columna extra 'temporal' para guardar el color del fondo.

Es decir, si tienes por ejemplo una tabla con 8 filas y 5 columnas, obtendrás un array de 8x5 y agregando la columna de fondos quedará de 8x6.

Te dejo un código de ejemplo que hice para que veas el funcionamiento:

```
function ordenar() {

  var libro = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var hojaOrd = libro.getSheetByName("ORDENAMIENTO");

  var datos = hojaOrd.getRange(1, 1, hojaOrd.getLastRow(),hojaOrd.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  var colores = hojaOrd.getRange(2, 2, hojaOrd.getLastRow()-1, 1).getBackgrounds();
  var coloresFondo = colores.map(fila=>fila[0])
  datos.shift();
  for(let i=0; i<datos.length; i++){

    let fila = datos[i];
    fila[4] = Number(fila[1].replace(/\./g,''))
    fila[5] = coloresFondo[i];
  }

  datos.sort(function(a, b) {
    var valorA = a[4]; // Obtener el valor de la segunda columna de la fila a
    var valorB = b[4]; // Obtener el valor de la segunda columna de la fila b

    if (valorA < valorB) {
      return -1; // a viene antes que b
    }else if (valorA > valorB) {
      return 1; // b viene antes que a
    }else {
      return 0; // a y b son iguales
    }
  });

  var datosPegar = datos.map(fila => fila.slice(0, parseInt(fila.length)-2));
  hojaOrd.getRange(2, 1, datosPegar.length, datosPegar[0].length).setValues(datosPegar);

  for(let i=0; i<datos.length; i++){

    let fila = datos[i];
    let indice = i+2;
    hojaOrd.getRange(indice, 2, 1, 1).setBackground(fila[5])

  }

}
```

Lo probé con este pequeño ejemplo:

[image: Datos iniciales]

[image: Datos ordenados]